# Processing Multiple POST Input Values with Python Bottle

Tags: python, bottle

In Bottle, let's say I have a form with 10 inputs:

```
<form method="POST" action="/machine" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="one" placeholder="one" required>
    <input type="text" name="two" placeholder="two" required>
    ...
    <input type="text" name="ten" placeholder="ten" required>
</form>
```

I want to then process all the potential inputs and don't want to do this statically by calling each one individually on the POST route (e.g. request.forms.get("one")).

Is there a way to process all the inputs in the form. I've been seeing request.params and request.query ...

```
@route('/machine', method='POST')
def machine_learn():
    my_dict = dict(request.params)
    return str(my_dict)
```

... but don't fully understand how I can use these to get all the input data as either a dictionary or list. When I use the above code, I get an empty dictionary

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.forms` returns a [Python Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) of all the inputs in the request.

So you can process the request dynamically like this

```
for key, value in request.forms.items():
  print("For name " + key + ", the value is " + value)
```

Comment: Welcome! Best of luck on the web app! :-)

Answer (score 0):

`request.forms` is an instance of `bottle.FormsDict` class. <sup>[1](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/blob/0.12.16/bottle.py#L1886)</sup>

When you examine `bottle.MultiDict` class with FormsDict subclasses, there is a `allitems` method that can be used to retrieve a list containing tuples of field name and value. <sup>[2](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/blob/0.12.16/bottle.py#L1833)</sup>

```
form_items = request.forms.allitems()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for some additional help.

```
def merge_dicts(*args):
    result = {}
    for dictionary in args:
        result.update(dictionary)
    return result

class Api(object):
    def __init__(self, user, request, option):
        self.user = user
        self.option = option
        self.payload = merge_dicts(dict(request.forms), dict(request.query.decode()))
```

This can now take any form, or query post and combine them into a payload.  The reason for the `dict()` is because Bottle technically doesn't return a true dict, instead it is a FormsDict which does not have all the features of a dict in place.  This makes that process simple, and turns everything into a dict.